# Menu Tabs Don't Respond

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tabs

Currently I'm making UI for my app. I use [Sliding Up Panel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) and [Sliding Tabs](https://github.com/joseedwin84/Android-Sliding-Tabs-With-Material-Design) [(tutorial with implementation explanation)](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html) features. Both work fine. I even managed to implement them in one project, but that's where problem comes in - Home and Event's tabs are unresponsive when I touch them(should open the page it's representing), but they change when I slide between tabs.

[image]

Here's my layout code. This is where the problem is. I'm sure of it.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />

 <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
    sothree:umanoParalaxOffset="100dp"
    sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView">

      <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ff0000">
        <com.ui.test.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>

      <!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#55eeeeee"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:id="@+id/dragView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/follow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/daimage" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

If I remove part that adds Sliding Up Panel features, clicking function enables.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />


        <com.ui.test.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnTouchListener{

    // Declaring Your View and Variables

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    CharSequence Titles[]={"Side","Front", "Result"};
    int Numboftabs =3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
        adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width



        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
            }
        });



        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

        tabs.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                return false;
            }   
        });




    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

        @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


}
```

Comment: Hi Oleksandr, tried switching to [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) from the Design Support Library?.. might be more responsive.

Comment: show java code. all i can say is the it has overrode it, is there anything in your library as onTabselected or of that sort? it there is go work around that area

Comment: I've added `MainActivity.java` to the question. The rest is identical to the links I provided.

Comment: I've spent 150 rep on this question. It would be a pity if it still won't be answered

Comment: don't worry you got 2 days, and i am here, will give you a solution less than 24hrs. ima try to recreate the scenario quick.

Comment: http://cdn2.screenjunkies.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/could-this-be-gog-132140.jpg

Comment: @OleksandrFirsov why don't you try  fernaMuruthi 's comment?

Comment: it's really not that different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building up on Amy's answer here, assuming the slidingUpPanel is blocking the onTouch for the tab buttons, then you can use the onTouch eventlistener to disallow parent layout to intercept any touch events like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width



    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });



    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);

    // THIS PART, ADD CODE HERE !
    tabs.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        return false;
        }
    });

}
```

**EDIT 1:**

the sliding up panel is like an overlay on top of its children, so if you keep the tab layout in the children, the sliding up panel's strip view will come right on top of your tab strip, and this sliding up panel's strip will stop the tab strip from recieving any click or touch events, so
when you are actually trying to touch or click the tabs you are not actually touching/clicking on the tabs because sliding up panel is on top of it. what you need to do is put the slidingtablayout outside the slidinguppanel layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <!--this is outside sliding up panel layout-->
    <com.example.www.slidinguppanelapp.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="#f0f0f0"/>
    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp">

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dragView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#55eeeeee"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="68dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/follow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:src="@drawable/blur_bg">
            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've added this to my MainActivity.java, but I get these errors for the first line: `Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "setOnTouchListener", invalid 
  AnnotationName
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)` and this `Syntax error on token "}", invalid ConstructorHeaderName` for the last one. What should I do?

Comment: So how can I fix this?

Comment: Well these look like syntax errors can you post the whole class code I would have to take a look at the complete class code to see the flower bracket structure

Comment: I provided it in the question.

Comment: where have you added the above code i mentioned in the answer exactly

Comment: no put the code where u actually have access to the tabs variable,  put the code at the end of oncreate

Comment: If I put it inside at the end of `onCreate` - I get a lot of errors that want me to drastically change the code. Are you sure it is correct?

Comment: Any ideas? Maybe I sound annoying, but I'm trying to solve the problem for over a week and it makes me frustrated.

Comment: those lines of code aren't anything special its just a touch event listener for your slidingtabslayout I don't understand how it can be causing so many errors? and the on touch function is also returning false so that it is not completely consuming that event

Comment: Me neither. Maybe try to run it on your PC?

Comment: No put the code at the end INSIDE the onCreate method

Comment: I understand that. But as I was saying before, there are a lot of errors. Check updated question with screenshot if you want

Comment: @OleksandrFirsov unfortunately I am not getting any of these errors just copy paste the onCreate metho I wrote in the answer and see if you get syntax errors that time, I'm assuming its some curly brace/punctuation marks that is causing the syntax error

Comment: @OleksandrFirsov OHHHHHHH I got it, its because i forgot to add the curly brackes () after View.OnTouchListener, change `View.OnTouchListener` to `View.OnTouchListener()` this is basics man... you should've caught this silly syntax mis type :(

Comment: Yeah, I know. But... Yeah, I know. Okay, so that cleared all those errors. I also added `onTouch()` method, to the activity. Tabs are unresponsive

Comment: what do you mean ontouch methods to the activity?

Comment: `public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)` at the end of `MainActivity.java`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93825/discussion-between-bhargav-and-oleksandr-firsov).

Comment: Yes, that would be nice

Comment: It worked! Needs some improvements, but now I'm getting somewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation:

> By default, the whole panel will act as a drag region and will intercept clicks and drag events. You can restrict the drag area to a specific view by using the `setDragView` method or `umanoDragView` attribute.

So I assume, that the Sliding Up Panel consumes your onClick on your Tabs - simply set the attributes as the documentation suggests.

Comment: Adding `umanoDragView` to `com.ui.test.SlidingTabLayout` doesn't change anything.

Comment: add it to your viewpager

Comment: moved  `sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView1"` to `ViewPager` - nothing changed

Comment: okey, viewpager was wrong. You have to add the umanoDragView to the view, where you want to enable the drag - since you want to have the viewpager, I suggest adding a simple <View/> element at the bottom of your first relative layout and make sure, that you dont have clickable content there.

I dont know if it works, but you can try to add the attribute to the second child (LinearLayout), so you can only drag from there?

Answer (score 0):

```
tabs.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        return false;
    }   
});
```

put this inside your onCreate()

Comment: There are a lot of errors. Check updated question for code and screenshot